# clang cast callExpr.getArg type to decl

Tags: clang, llvm-c++-api

i want to implement a interpreter based on Clang.i meet a problem. i creat a `map` to store vardecl and it corresponding int value. but when i visit callExpr,the function callExpr.getArg return type is expr,i want to cast it to decl type. how can i figure this problem?

example

```
int a = 10;
int main(){
  PRINT(a) //self-define function
}
```

mymapdecl[a] = 10,but PRINTExpr.getArg type is expr.
I use `dyn_cast<DeclRefExpr>(left)`to get DeclRefExpr type,but it return null pointer.